# Calculating patient-years from average follow-up

Tags: time-series, epidemiology

I need to estimate patient-years for some studies, in which this data is not reported. However, I do have total population and mean follow-up.

Would it be suitable to estimate the number of patient-years by multiplying the total number of patients for the average follow-up time?

For example: 100 patients, with a mean follow-up of 2.2 years = 220 patient-years.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Many papers compute mean follow-up time among only those without an event.   So you cannot compute person-years of follow-up from many studies, i.e., you cannot compute the exponential distribution hazard rate.   You can use the mean follow-up time among non-events as a useful index of length of follow-up though.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thank you for your reply. Indeed, it is assumed that the mean follow-up time reported is for the whole cohort (both with events and non-events). Would it be possible to calculate the patient-year in this case?

Comment: Yes in that special case it's as simple as it looks.